# Modifying or hiding a form's caption tooltip

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-xp, tooltip

We have an MDI form which contains some number of child forms which have varying captions showing the currently loaded document's filename.  When the child forms are maximized their title text gets placed in the parent window's title bar which often results in the text being too long to fit in the bar and Windows is nice enough to add ellipses and truncate the text.

However, when you hover over the title bar of the main window, it shows a tooltip with what should be the entire string, but instead the tooltip often contains a small fraction of the string.  For example, if the main form's text was:

```
Program1 - Filename:[Really_long_filename_that_doesnt_fit.file]
```

It would appear as the following in the tooltip:

```
Program1 - Filename:[Really_long_filename_t
```

Edit: It always truncates the tooltip at exactly 100 characters, which leads me to believe that it's some upper limit specified somewhere.

Is there a way to change this so it displays the entire string, or if not, to disable the tooltip altogether?

Any language is acceptable, although we're doing this in C#.

Comment: What exactly are you hovering over? Is it the taskbar entry or the very top bar of the parent mdi form?

Comment: The parent MDI form's title bar.  You can replicate the behavior by resizing any form so that the title text is truncated.  Then hover over the title bar.  It seems insignificant but the customer noticed it and now it's a problem :P

Comment: Are you running this on XP? In Vista I don't get a tooltip.

Comment: Yes, this is in XP.  I'll update the question.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? It shows the full tooltip.

Comment: Once I called TrackMouseEvent your solution worked pretty good Jeff, however, it still displays the old tooltip if you hover the required amount of time.

Comment: How about the latest code I posted, give that a try...

Comment: Same results, I still end up with two tooltips: one full-length tooltip and the windows-provided one (which is truncated).  I'm thinking if there's not a way to turn off the windows tooltip I might have to find another workaround.

Comment: I have it not passing along the mouse messages to the base window procedure now for the title bar, see if that works, hopefully it does :)

Comment: So close, but it still is showing the second tooltip.  I have a suspicion that the tooltip isn't managed by my form at all.  Discarding all the mouse messages still has the tooltip appear.

Comment: I ran this on another xp box and it worked fine. What version of .NET are you using and what service pack is your XP box? Is your xp 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I deleted my test stuff and pasted your code in and it's still displaying the second tooltip.  XP SP2 32 bit on .NET 2.0

Comment: Im curious so Im gonna setup a virtual machine to see if I can reproduce this

Comment: Something that I've had to work around to get it to process the messages correctly was to call TrackMouseEvent after any WM_NCMOUSEMOVE.  I'm running in "Classic" windows mode (non-skinned) which has some quirks with non-client messages apparently.

Comment: I installed xp pro sp2 x86 on a virtual machine and installed the .net framework 2.0 sp2 on it and ran my code and I only saw one tooltip. Have you tried running the app on other computers?

Comment: Here's a link to what I am seeing: http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/57ce577623.jpg

Comment: When I comment out the entire WndProc method I do not see a tooltip. The only thing I can think of is that the machine you are running this on has something that creates the extra tooltip. Sorry I did not come up with a definitive answer on this one.

Comment: Ah sorry for the late reply, try your sample with your windows and buttons style set to "Windows Classic." This apparently modifies the behavior of some of the WM_NCxx messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses a manual tooltip and timer to show / hide a caption when the mouse moves over the title bar.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
    private Timer toolTipTimer = new Timer();
    private bool canShowToolTip = true;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x2A0: // WM_NCMOUSEHOVER
                return;
            case (int)0x00A0: // WM_NCMOUSEMOVE
                if (m.WParam == new IntPtr(0x0002)) // HT_CAPTION
                {
                    if (canShowToolTip)
                    {
                        canShowToolTip = false;
                        toolTip.Show(this.Text, this, this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position), toolTip.AutoPopDelay);
                        toolTipTimer.Start();
                    }
                }
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form child = new Form();
        child.Text = "Program1 - Filename:[Really_long_filename_that_doesnt_fit.file] AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
        child.MdiParent = this;
        child.Show();
        toolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
        toolTipTimer.Interval = toolTip.AutoPopDelay;
        toolTipTimer.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            canShowToolTip = true;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: The filename itself is well over 100 characters so even stripped to the bare minimum it will be truncated.

Comment: I'm not getting the WM_NCMOUSELEAVE event and subsequently I only see the tooltip once.  It seems like it may work if I can iron out some kinks.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had something more helpful for you, but unfortunately, I don't think that there's a way around this. You may either shorten your filenames or have to deal with it :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the filenames of the files we work with are generated by a custom FPGA and have long machine-generated filenames.

Comment: :( i'm sorry guy... sometimes the best answer is the one that saves you a lot of time looking for one that doesn't exist. for your sake i hope some supergenius has a way to figure it out for you, but my experience says that's just a UI "feature" included in the forms :\